# Reading Null Values in Byte Array

Tags: c#

I am trying to loop through a byte array (sample below) reading the values to then insert those into a database

I loop through keeping track of the position

```
    byte[] data;
    long position=0;
    while (position < data.Length)
    {
        position = Conversion.Extract(data, out mydata, position);
        position = Conversion.Extract(data, out nextitem, position);
    }

    public static long Extract(byte[] message, out int variable, long position)
    {
        const int length = 4; // the length of an int

        if (message.Length >= position + length)
        {
            variable = BitConverter.ToInt32(message, (int)position);
            return position + length;
        }

        // there was a problem
        variable = 0;
        return -1;
    }
```

The data i have contains some null values, how can i extract these and successfully move onto the next value. At present if i come across a null value i dont know how to detect this and move onto the next item. Can anyone help at all

```
6F 72 67 61 6E 69 73 61 74 69 6F 6E 49 64 3D 33
26 10 00 00 00 50 65 6F 70 6C 65 50 65 6F 70 6C
65 4C 69 6E 6B 6A 08 00 00 09 00 00 00 0E 00 00
00 53 65 6E 69 6F 72 50 65 72 73 6F 6E 49 64 0E
00 00 00 4A 75 6E 69 6F 72 50 65 72 73 6F 6E 49
64 11 00 00 00 53 65 6E 69 6F 72 50 65 72 73 6F
6E 4D 69 73 49 64 11 00 00 00 4A 75 6E 69 6F 72
50 65 72 73 6F 6E 4D 69 73 49 64 08 00 00 00 4C
69 6E 6B 54 79 70 65 16 00 00 00 50 61 72 65 6E
74 61 6C 52 65 73 70 6F 6E 73 69 62 69 6C 69 74
79 08 00 00 00 50 72 69 6F 72 69 74 79 0B 00 00
00 4C 61 73 74 55 70 64 61 74 65 64 07 00 00 00
44 65 6C 65 74 65 64 01 00 00 00 D7 0A 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 80 C3 29
C6 85 BF CE 08 00 02 00 00 00 3C 0C 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 83 76 C6
85 BF CE 08 00 03 00 00 00 3C 0C 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 0E 76 C6 85
BF CE 08 00 04 00 00 00 67 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 70 CA 4B C6 85 BF
CE 08 00 05 00 00 00 67 0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 70 CA 4B C6 85 BF CE
08 00 06 00 00 00 9B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 C0 BE B2 C5 85 BF CE 08
00 06 00 00 00 AD 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 02 10 6D F5 C5 85 BF CE 08 00
06 00 00 00 3F 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 02 80 59 11 C6 85 BF CE 08 00 07
00 00 00 E3 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 01 C0 D0 2C C6 85 BF CE 08 00 08 00
00 00 9B 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 01 C0 BE B2 C5 85 BF CE 08 00 08 00 00
00 AD 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 01 10 6D F5 C5 85 BF CE 08 00 08 00 00 00
C9 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 01 20 76 FA C5 85 BF CE 08 00 08 00 00 00 3F
0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
01 B0 CE 11 C6 85 BF CE 08 00 09 00 00 00 E3 0A
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
90 5B 2C C6 85 BF CE 08 00 0A 00 00 00 C9 09 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 20
76 FA C5 85 BF CE 08 00 0B 00 00 00 F6 08 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 E0 C9
D2 C5 85 BF CE 08 00 0C 00 00 00 F6 08 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 F0 2C C9
C5 85 BF CE 08 00 0E 00 00 00 91 09 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 C0 C7 EF C5
85 BF CE 08 00 0F 00 00 00 91 09 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 90 52 EF C5 85
```

```
SeniorPersonId | JuniorPersonId | SeniorPersonMisId | JuniorPersonMisId | LinkType | ParentalResponsibility | Priority | LastUpdated              Deleted
1              | 2775           | {null}            | {null}            | {null}   | 0                      | 1        | 2012-02-22 14:31:18.200 | {null}
2              | 3132           | {null}            | {null}            | {null}   | 0                      | {null}   | 2012-02-22 14:31:18.703 | {null}
3              | 3132           | {null}            | {null}            | {null}   | 0                      | {null}   | 2012-02-22 14:31:18.700 | {null}
4              | 2919           | {null}            | {null}            | {null}   | 0                      | 1        | 2012-02-22 14:31:18.423 | {null}
```

Comment: Whats in the data array? Where does the data come from? Whats null for you?

Comment: Your conversion code is simply no match for the data.  It clearly contains a mix of strings and integers.  The first line of hex is "organisationId=3".  You will need to find out more about the way the data is structured.

Answer (score 0):

If with null value you mean a null byte then this should work:

```
bool HasNullByteInside(Int32 n)
{
    return (n & 0xff000000 == 0) ||
           (n & 0x00ff0000 == 0) ||
           (n & 0x0000ff00 == 0) ||
           (n & 0x000000ff == 0);
}
```